# Forward www subdomain to domain

Tags: subdomain, forward

How do I auto forward/turn/convert (whatever the correct term is) URLs entered as www.example.com or www.example.com/blah/blah to example.com or example.com/blah/blah? I basically want to push anything coming in with the www subdomain to forward to the domain including the paths (if any).

Comment: You're not using the term top-level domain correctly. A TLD is .com, .org, .co.uk, etc.

Comment: it would be helpful to know which tools you are looking into using; this also might be better asked on serverfault

Comment: Thank you for the very constructive comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your htaccess file use this

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```